# Regarding cell identifiers UITableViewCell iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having a dynamic table view containing 7 different sections. I am using different cell identifiers for each of the sections, namely, identifier 10 for 1st section, 20 for 2nd, 30 for 3rd and so on (70 for 7th). The code for this is:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier;
UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%d",@"Cell",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Section 7th (CellIdentifier 60) contains a plus button and on clicking that plus button, a new section will be created between section 6th and 7th, that is, number of sections will be incremented by 1 and the 7th section will now become 8th section (CellIdentifier 70). The new section is inserted as section 7th (CellIdentifier 60) using insertSections method of UITableView and this new section will contain a delete button (in place of plus button). Now, If I delete this section (clicking on delete button, the method used is deleteSections of UITableView) then the 7th section gets deleted and the 8th section becomes 7th section (CellIdentifier again becomes 60) (earlier it was 7th only). Now, the problem arises. If I scroll the table view, then the section which I deleted reappears overlapped with the section containing plus button (both were having CellIdentifier 60 at some point of time).
Does anybody has any solution for this?? please help me.

Comment: If the cells all look the same, then there is no need to create different cells for each section. Using the one type of cell will make your tabeleview much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use unique identifier for each section. They cannot overlap - even at different times. Cells with any specific CellIdentifier are reused over and over.

Just make sure that your oft-appearing and disappearing section has a totally unique cell identifier and you should be ok.